# How to convert a set of flv frames to flv video stream?

Tags: flash, video, video-streaming, flv

I'm getting raw video frames from a video monitoring device continuously, then I converted them to flv frames. What I want to do is send these frames to flash player, then user can play this LIVE video using a web browser.

I searched on Google for a long time, but I cannot find answers to these questions:

How is flv video stream structured? I found SWF File Structure Specification and FLV File Structure Specification, but I cannot find docs like "FLV Video Stream Specification"..

And after I know how flv stream is structured, how should I send them to flash player? Need I create a server socket and listening incoming request, then respond with current flv frame? I heard that Red5 can stream flv files, but can it stream flv frames on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you mean by an 'flv frame'. You either have raw frames, or flv tags. An flv file is simply concatenated flv tags in monotonically increasing DTS order, prepended with a simple header. The document you are looking for is here: http://download.macromedia.com/f4v/video_file_format_spec_v10_1.pdf

Finally streaming flv, generally, uses a  protocol called RTMP. It is basically flv with extra timing an connection management. red5 is an RTMP server.

Comment: Hi, Now I have raw video frames (and I have converted them to flv tags), how could I feed them to red5 server to start video streaming? I searched a lot but only finding "red5 streaming flv files" but not "streaming flv frames". Thanks

Comment: librtmp. Part of the rtmpdump package.